# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: php, java, android-studio, webservice, android-volley

Me encuentro haciendo una validacion de un login, en android estudio, utilizo  volley para la comunicacion con mi web service, todo se valida hasta que hago la validacion de la contraseña, la cual está tratada con bcrypt, y me arroja el error org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of, he intentado con el tipo de retorno, como objeto o array pero no logro solucionar ese error

Este es mi web service

```php
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once './ConexionPDO.php';
require_once '../assets/util/password.php';
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

if ($json != null) {
    $objjson = json_decode($json);    
    $cliente = $objjson->cliente;
    $personal = $objjson->personal;
    $pass = $objjson->pass;
    $obj1 = new ConexionPDO();
    try {
        $result = array();
        $cnx0 = $obj1->conectar();
        $sql = $cnx0->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE usuario = :nombreUsr;");
        $sql->bindParam(':nombreUsr', $cliente);
        if ($sql->execute()) {
            $resultset = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($resultset == false) {
                $result["answer"] = "NO SE ENCONTRO AL USUARIO";
                $result['user'] =  $cliente;
            } else{
                    $idCliente = $resultset['id'];
                    $cnx1 = $obj1->conectar();
                    $sql1 = $cnx1->prepare("SELECT id,pass from personal where user = :usuario and idParent = :idCliente;");
                    $sql1->execute(array('usuario' => $personal, ':idCliente' => $idCliente));
                    $resultset1 = $sql1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    if ($resultset1['id'] == null) {                        
                        $result["answer"] = "NO SE ENCONTRO AL Personal";
                    } else {                        
                        $hash = $resultset1['pass'];
                        if ((password_verify($pass, $hash))) {
                            $result["answer"] = "Contraseña correcta";
                        } else {
                            $result["answer"] = "Contraseña incorrecta";
                        }
                    }

            }
            //$result['resp'] = $resultset;
        } else {
            $result["answer"] = "No se pudo realizar la consulta";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result["answer"] = 'Excepción capturada al conectar con BDD: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } finally {
        $sql->closeCursor();
        $cnx0 = null;
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
} else {
    $result["answer"] =  "NO SE RECIBIERON LOS DATOS CORRECTAMENTE";
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

La validacion de cliente y personal la realiza sin problema, pero en la contraseña manda ese error.

Este es mi codigo java.

```java
private void jsonRequest(){
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonParams.put("cliente",etcliente.getText().toString());
            jsonParams.put("personal",etpersonal.getText().toString());
            jsonParams.put("pass",etpass.getText().toString());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlLogin, jsonParams, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                String test = response.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La comunicación falló "+ error.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Parece ser que en ese caso la respuesta llega vacía. ¿Has tratado de mostrar la respuesta en el LogCat? ¿Qué muestra?

Comment: @A.Cedano En efecto estaba vacio, lo solucioné agregando una bandera al dato a enviar hacia el consumidor. Gracias por contestar

Comment: Te recomiendo que controles todas las eventualidades en el código PHP, generando adecuadamente un array. Supongamos que nuestro array de salida se llamará `$outPut`. En todos los sitios que haya errores creas esto: `$outPut["error"]="Mensaje de error en ese lugar";` Luego mandas al final del código `echo json_encode($outPut);` y, en Android, antes de hacer lo que sea, verificas primero si la respuesta no tiene una clave `error`. Eso te permitirá tener un código robusto en el cual la App nunca hará crash ante un error no cubierto.

Answer (score 1):

El error :

> JSONException: End of input at character 0

**sucede porque la respuesta json que tratas de "parsear" es vacía no contiene en realidad un json**

Asegura que dentro de `onResponse()` en realidad obtengas en la variable `response`, un json valido:

```
sonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlLogin, jsonParams, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                String test = response.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```